# Magento 2 Create Custom Field for Image Visibility same as hide from default page field

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, product-images, image, media-images

I want to create one more checkbox which set the image as default. If Image is set to default then only want to add one "`default_image`" class on the product image on listing page.

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.